# Beamer: Change text displayed in footer

Tags: beamer

I want to use a theme (Madrid) for a beamer produced slideshow. The problem is that the text in the preamble's \institute{} (which follows on my name) is too long, so it gets cut off by the next item in the footer, the title.

I would like to change the text displayed for the \institute{} in the footer, but not on my title page. I am a bit overwhelmed by the beamer guide. Could you please help me with this comman?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
\institute[version for footline]{version for title page}
```